# Determine a position of the Org Mode code block?

Tags: org-mode

In my Org Mode document I have the following two blocks

```
#+NAME: fcn
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var pt=(point)
  (list pt (point))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: fcn
| 56 | 56 |

#+NAME: second_block
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var a=(point) b=fcn(pt=(point))
  (list a b)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: second_block
| 213 | (13 13) |
```

I want to determine a position of the `second_block` and pass it to `fcn`.  As a result of the `second_block` I am expecting to obtain something like this

```
| XYZ | (XYZ 13) |
```

where `XYZ` is a position of the `second_block` (it can be any point that belongs to the `second_block`: ultimately `XYZ` should work with [property API functions](http://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-property-API.html) as a `POM`).

Moreover, I would like to have a solution **that works independent of the current cursor position**. For instance It should work properly also when the cursor position doesn't point to the `second_block`, for example after executing all code blocks in current buffer (with `C-c C-v b`). **In this context the `point` function might be incorrectly applied here**, which I am aware of.

Secondly, why is `b` variable equal to `(13 13)` after execution of the `second_block`?

Comment: Did you try `org-babel-map-src-blocks`? I think that when blocks are evaluated they are copied into a different buffer, so position will not be the same as in the original buffer.

Comment: @wvxvw  Nothing changed after replacing `(point)` by `(org-babel-map-src-blocks nil)`. If blocks are evaluated in another buffer this problem might be unsolvable.

Comment: Oh, that's not what I meant. `org-babel-map-src-blocks` is a function that calls your function with the argument being a struct that describes the src block. On top of other things stored in this struct, there's its position in the buffer.

Comment: @wvxvw I see. How should I define an argument describing the function to be evaluated for `org-babel-map-src-blocks`? Can I do this by reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23726135/5691066 here's some example usage (solving a different problem, but you could copy some code from it).

Comment: @wvxvw Thank you! It is a real challenge for me though :)